# WHERE does not work with LEFT JOIN

Tags: php, mysqli, left-join, where-clause

I have two hypothetical tables 'applications' and 'jobs'. I want to join both tables to display results based on 'jobs_id' and logged user (which is a global variable)

Now, I have a simple query:

```
<?php
 $user = 'root';
 $pass = '';
 $db = new PDO( 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydb', $user, $pass );
 $sql = " SELECT e.application_id, e.candidate_login, e.company_id, e.jobs_id, u.jobs_title, u.jobs_manager 
    FROM applications
        AS e LEFT JOIN jobs
        AS u ON e.jobs_id = u.jobs_id 
            WHERE e.candidate_login='[usr_login]'
            ";  
 $query = $db->prepare( $sql );
 $query->execute();
 $results = $query->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
?>
```

my problems is that WHERE clause prohibits data from being shown.

I am using variable '[usr_login]' to display only results that belong to a logged user. And it works for all other queries but this one.

When I change that variable to a constant (e.g. email address) then results are displayed.

I am also positive that variable exists as other data is based on it, and that works as expected.

So my question is, what is wrong with that WHERE clause?

Can anyone point me in the right direction, please?

Comment: What is the data in [usr_login] ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the bracket [] notation, have you tried binding $usr_login with `bindParam`? http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: Your SQL indentation is odd given that the parse is (from ((applications
        AS e) LEFT JOIN (jobs
        AS u) ON (e.jobs_id = u.jobs_id)))
           (WHERE (...)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to reference a variable in an SQL statement is with either `?` or a named parameter, preceded by a colon, like `:usr_login`, and you should not quote it.

Then you need to bind your actual value to it:

```
$sql = " SELECT    e.application_id, e.candidate_login, e.company_id, e.jobs_id, 
                   u.jobs_title, u.jobs_manager 
         FROM      applications AS e 
         LEFT JOIN jobs AS u 
                ON e.jobs_id = u.jobs_id 
             WHERE e.candidate_login = ?
         ";
$query = $db->prepare( $sql );
$query->bind_param('s', $usr_login);
$query->execute();
```

You must of course have the variable `$usr_login` (with a string value) for this to work.